# Get all elements of a group property in Gambas

Tags: controls, gambas

The group property in gamba's controls is extremely handy.

But how can I access all controls of a defined group in code?

Die Eigenschaft Group ist über "btn.group" nicht verfügbar.

I would like to set certain properties of list of controls defined as a group in code.